# MSBuild - how to copy files that may or may not exist?

Tags: msbuild, copy

I have a situation where I need to copy a few specific files in a MSBuild script, but they may or may not exist. If they don't exist it's fine, I don't need them then. But the standard `<copy>` task throws an error if it cannot find each and every item in the list...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the **Exists** condition on Copy task.

```
<CreateItem Include="*.xml">
  <Output ItemName="ItemsThatNeedToBeCopied" TaskParameter="Include"/>
</CreateItem>

<Copy SourceFiles="@(ItemsThatNeedToBeCopied)"
      DestinationFolder="$(OutputDir)"
      Condition="Exists('%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
```

Comment: Thanx! I had forgotten about these! :)

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that instead of `%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename)%(Extension)`, one can simply use `%(FullPath)` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171476.aspx)

Comment: Mind that when you are using transform when providing `SourceFiles`, you need to provide the exact same transform in `Condition`

Answer (score 10):

The easiest would be to use the ContinueOnError flag http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
        <MySourceFiles Include="a.cs;b.cs;c.cs"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CopyFiles">
        <Copy
            SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"
            DestinationFolder="c:\MyProject\Destination"
            ContinueOnError="true"
        />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

But if something else is wrong you will not notice it. So the condition exist from madgnome's answer would be better.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can mark MySourceFiles as SkipUnchangedFiles="true" and it won't copy the files if they already exist.

Comment: It won't copy the files only if they have the same size and same modification date, otherwise files still will be overridden.