# Vs.net Setup Project conditional if File Exists

Tags: visual-studio, file, setup-project, conditional-statements, exists

Friends How to Set This Code VS.NET Setup Conditions.

```
<Copy Condition="!Exists($(DestPath)database.dat)"
      SourceFiles="$(SrcPath)database.dat"
      DestinationFolder="$(DestPath)"/>
```

[Source Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102503/visual-studio-setup-project-conditional-if-file-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach:

- go to Launch Conditions Editor in your setup project
- create a new file search and configure it to find your file
- remember the installer property used by this search
- go to File System Editor
- select your file
- in its Properties pane set Condition field to the search property negated; for example, if the search property is named MY_FILE_SEARCH, the condition can be:

  NOT MY_FILE_SEARCH

This way the file is installed only if the search doesn't find anything.