# Updating Windows .net Program with installer

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, installation

I created a small simple Windows program in Visual Studio, the i added a Setup project to the solution. 
Now i can install my program, and when i update something in the Windows program i can quickly build a new installer, however i got 1 problem. 
My windows program contains a settings file and when i Uodate/Reinstall my settings file is reset, How can this be avoided, i want to be able to update my program from a setup file without resetting the settings file ?

So anyone plz help me or point the right direction :)

Comment: I would consider you reading this:
http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/

Comment: Srry i know, but i could'nt find any tags with installer and Visual Studio. And du to me being new and low rep, i cant create new tags :)

Comment: I changed the tags for you, fyi the visual-studio tag already existed ;)

Comment: thx :), i will look at answers a bit later :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve what you want by changing the settings file's property in the VS setup project to the following:

```
Transitive = False
```

And if you want the file to remain there even after uninstallation, then set the following property for the file as well:

```
Permanent = True
```

**Warning:** Setting the Transitive property mentioned above may have other less than desirable side effects. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/928tb19t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx for more information.

Another alternative is to add a **Condition** to the file in the setup project, as described in the following link:-

[Visual Studio Setup Project conditional if File Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102503/visual-studio-setup-project-conditional-if-file-exists)