# Visual Studio Setup Project conditional if File Exists - Search user folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I've read the following post:

[Visual Studio Setup Project conditional if File Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102503/visual-studio-setup-project-conditional-if-file-exists)

What I need is to search for a file in the current user's application data folder. MS says 
that you can use bracketed special folder names such as [ProgramFilesFolder]:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdh0hak4(v=vs.100).aspx
Now I found a list of special folder names:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2esdf4x(v=vs.100).aspx

So, now I don't know how to make a bracketed name from "User's Application Data". Can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems not really possible, so I used Custom action instead. The trick was adding my custom action both to Install and Commit phases, though it only searched for file in Commit phase.
If it is added only to Commit phase, then I got "MyInstallHelper.InstallState not found" error.