# How to keep files from a previous install

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I'm working on a program that allows users to remove files to replace with their own files (sound or image files). In the event the user uninstalls and re-installs the program, the files that were replaced by the user should be preserved and not replaced.

I've done a bit of reading and trial and failure on using the Search Target Machine part of the Setup and Deployment project and it has failed every single time.

My current method is the one prescribed here: (But this is for VS 2008, not 2010 the one I am using):
[Visual Studio Setup Project conditional if File Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102503/visual-studio-setup-project-conditional-if-file-exists)
This is exactly what I'm doing:(Except for instead of  or (The Files Name), I'm using the actual file name or property.

```
Search Target Machine:
    <Search Item>
        Depth (1) (It's kept in a subfolder)
        FileName (The Files Name)
        Folder [TARGETDIR]
        MaxDate through MinVersion are kept blank
        Property: <FILENAMEEXISTS>
```

And for the file itself:

```
 Condition: NOT <FILENAMEEXISTS> (Exactly like that, case and everything).
```

What am I doing wrong here?